# Attempting to use an int[] as a typename template, compiler not recognizing argument within prototype for function min

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm hitting a wall. This code is suppose to utilize typename templates and implement them within my functions. The first two prototyped functions work as intended. The third prototype, min, is giving me trouble. It's suppose to return the lowest value within the passed array. However, it would appear as if I didn't declare the template properly to function with an array.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'T1'  Project6    56  
Error   C2446   '<': no conversion from 'T1' to 'int'   Project6    60  
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'T1'  Project6    62
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // used for rand

template<typename T>
void assignRandom(T dataValue); // fills array with random values

template<typename T>
void print(T dataValue); // outputs array

template<typename T1>
T1 min(T1 dataValue); // identifies lowest value within array

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int data0[10];

    assignRandom(data0);
    cout << "Array of integer: ";
    print(data0);
    cout << min(data0);

    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void assignRandom(T dataValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        dataValue[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    return;
}

template<typename T>
void print(T dataValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << dataValue[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return;
}

template<typename T1>
T1 min(T1 dataValue)
{
    T1 minimum;

    minimum = dataValue[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (dataValue[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = dataValue[i];
        }
    }

    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: You need to call it like this: `max<int*>(data0)`, or something to that effect.

Comment: You are hiding something from us. The error message talks about `T2` which is not part of your source code.

Comment: there is an std::min. stop using `using namespace std` and see what happens. if you *really* don't want the std on cout/cin/endl use `using std::cout`, `using std::cin`, `using std::endl`, that will only bring in the specific objects.

Comment: My apologies, add incorrect compiler errors from an earlier attempt to fix it. I've added the correct errors.

Comment: In your min function, dataValue and minimum variables are of diferents types, but you are saying that they are the same. You must solve this

Answer (score 1):

Your template argument `T1` is being deduced as an `int*`. So you function min looks like this to the compiler:

```
int* min(int* dataValue)
{
    int* minimum;

    minimum = dataValue[0]; // dataValue[0] is an int
```

If you change your declaration of `min` to look like:

```
template<typename T1>
T1 min(T1* dataValue)
```

then `T1` will be deduced as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a fixed array to functions that don't actually accept a fixed array as input.  Your array will thus *decay* to a pointer to the first element, causing the functions to deduce their template parameter as `int*`, and all information about the array's actual size will be lost.  If you ever change your array to a different size, you would have to update the functions as well.  You want to avoid that.

Try this instead, which allows the functions to take the fixed array as-is and will deduce its size correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // used for rand

template<typename T, size_t N>
void assignRandom(T (&dataValue)[N]); // fills array with random values

template<typename T, size_t N>
void print(T (&dataValue)[N]); // outputs array

template<typename T, size_t N>
T min(T (&dataValue)[N]); // identifies lowest value within array

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int data0[10];

    assignRandom(data0);
    cout << "Array of integer: ";
    print(data0);
    cout << min(data0);

    return 0;
}

template<typename T, size_t>
void assignRandom(T (&dataValue)[N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        dataValue[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void print(T (&dataValue)[N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << dataValue[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
T min(T (&dataValue)[N])
{
    T minimum = dataValue[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (dataValue[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = dataValue[i];
        }
    }

    return minimum;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/gHxOWO)

Answer (score 0):

```
int data0[10];
```

is an array of 10 `int`s, so in

```
template<typename T1>
T1 min(T1 dataValue)
```

`data0` will decay to a pointer and provide the type of `int*` for `T1`. That means

```
T1 minimum;
```

is

```
int * minimum;
```

a pointer to an `int` and that means

```
minimum = dataValue[0];
```

is trying to assign a single integer, `dataValue[0]`, to a pointer, `minimum`.  The remaining errors are similar.

Quick hack fix: remove the pointer from the template deduction

```
template<typename T1>
T1 min(T1 * dataValue);
```